# Using mem_fun_ref with a proxy object

Tags: c++, std, c++03

I'm trying to use `std::mem_fun_ref` (Yes, the deprecated
version. Reasons below) to call a member function through a proxy.

```
template<typename T>
struct proxy {
  T& operator*() { return *t; }
  T* operator->() { return t; }
  // no address of etc
  T* t;
};

struct A {void foo() {}};

int main()
{
  A a;
  proxy<A> pa = {&a};
  std::mem_fun_ref_t<void, A>
    fn = std::mem_fun_ref(&A::foo);
  fn(pa); // borks
  return 0;
}
```

This works well with C++11 `std::mem_fn` but not `boost::mem_fn`, but
I can use neither of those, as I need to specify the type of the
binder in another place and the type of the resulting binder is
unspecified for `boost::mem_fn`. This wouldn't be a problem if I could
use `decltype` but I can't as the code needs to be compatible with
C++03.

What is the easiest way to work around this? A custom
`mem_fun_through_proxy`?

Edit: Another caveat is that the `proxy` class cannot be changed.

Comment: What if you add an `operator T&() { return *t }` to your proxy?

Comment: @KerrekSB Ah, I forgot. Changing the proxy is also not possible. In fact, it is an iterator.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche I'm not in control of the call site and need this to be called in a generic way.

Comment: What do you have control over? The functor type and creation apparently?

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche Exactly. I was hoping to accomplish this with the least amount of boilerplate and now have another functor wrapper `deref` that performs the dereference and passes the result on to the `mem_fun_ref_t`. Needless to say that this is a brittle thing in C++03.

Comment: You need some kind of wrapper or a more convenient functor/binder library, so your solution sounds reasonable and reusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Georg recommended, I implemented my own solution. Here is the short version:

```
// snipped solution: does not include const version and hack for void
// returns

#include <functional>

namespace mine {

template<typename Ret, typename T>
class mem_fun_ref_t : public std::unary_function<T, Ret>
{
public:
  explicit
  mem_fun_ref_t(Ret (T::*f)())
  : f(f) { }

  template<typename U>
  Ret
  operator()(U& u) const
  { return (*u.*f)(); }

  Ret
  operator()(T& t) const
  { return (t.*f)(); }

private:
  Ret (T::*f)();
};

} // mine

template<typename T>
struct proxy {
  T& operator*() { return *t; }
  T* operator->() { return t; }
  // no address of etc
  T* t;
};

struct X {
  int foo() {return 23;}
};

int main()
{
  mine::mem_fun_ref_t<int, X> fn(&X::foo);
  X x;
  // normal
  fn(x);
  proxy<X> px = {&x};
  fn(px);
  return 0;
}
```